# my computer (windows 7) does not support WEB GL graphics accelerator

Tags: windows-7

I tried to run `Google Earth Pro` but it won't start.

It displays this message:

`Your computer does not support WEB GL graphics accelerator.`

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check this site - https://get.webgl.org - if you don't see the spinning cube, the link will send you to the appropriate support site for your browser.

This is what you should see, if your browser supports WebGL [presumably you'd get a different message if it doesn't]

[image]

More detailed information is obtainable from [WebGL Report](http://webglreport.com) which will include whether your graphics card is capable of supporting it.